# Python and Selenium get value of specific html cell

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to get the text of a cell in a table of a html with python and selenium, but I get this error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"name","selector":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_tblHistorico"}

The html:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_divTabelaHistorico">
    <br />
    <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_tblHistorico" class="tablefq" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_tdTitulo" class="tituloTV" height="20" colspan="6">XX</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="TDTVHeader" width="4%"><a id='aSinalMain' class='sinal hand' onclick='aSinalMain_onClick(this)'>[+]</a></td>
            <td class="TDTVHeader" colspan="1">XXXnbsp;</td>
            <td class="TDTVHeader" colspan="1">XXXbsp;</td>
            <td class="TDTVHeader" colspan="1">XXXsp;</td>
            <td class="TDTVHeader" colspan="1">XXX</td>
            <td class="TDTVHeader" colspan="1">XXX&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1"><a id='aSinal' class='sinal hand'>[+]</a></td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XXX</td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XXX</td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XX</td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XX</td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XX</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:none;">
            <td class="TDFQ historico" colspan="6"><div class=scroll>I WANT HERE HERE HERE</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1"><a id='aSinal' class='sinal hand'>[+]</a></td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XXXp;</td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XXX&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XXXT;</td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XXX</td>
            <td class="TDFQ" colspan="1">XXX&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Python code:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_tblHistorico')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code.Let me know if that helps.You need JavaScripts executor to get the text of hiddden field.

```
eletext=driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='scroll']"))
print(eletext)
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: The loop brings only the tags tr.. Do not bring the tag tr <tr style="display:none;"> <tr style="display:none;">
            <td class="TDFQ historico" colspan="6"><div class=scroll>I WANT HERE HERE HERE</div></td>

Comment: I have updated my answer to get the value You wanted.Please accept my answer if it helps.

Comment: Thank you Kajal Kundu
This code solved my problem...I was trying to get this text during a long time.Thank you

Comment: Can you please accept my answer by click on accept button on my code message.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you are looking for "id" no for "name", so use the method:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_tblHistorico')
```

This would give you an element with the entire table.

If you know something else about the cell that you want, you could find for that specific element.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

For example, to get the text that you marked in your post you can use this because there is only one tag with that class name:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('scroll')
text = div.text
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to get the desired element by a CSS selector.

[This](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector) is the method you want to use.

The right CSS selector expression would be the following string.

```
#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_tblHistorico.TDFQ historico
```